# How to preserve caller informaion in java dynamic proxy

Tags: scala, dynamic, reflection, proxy

Suppose I have below pseudo scala code using dynamic proxy:

```
trait IClient {
  def multiply(a : Int) = Int
}

class MyInvocationHandler extends InvocationHandler {
  def invoke(proxy: Any, method: Method, args: Array[AnyRef]): AnyRef = {
    //do nothing
}}

class factory[P]() {
  val clientClass = implicitly[ClassTag[P]].runtimeClass

  def getProxy() : P = java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
    getClass.getClassLoader,
    Array(clientClass),
    new MyInvocationHandler()).asInstanceOf[P]
}

def main(): Int = {
  (new factory[IClient]).getProxy().multiply(1)
}
```

Now I want to pass below information to MyInvocationHandler.invoke:
 1. multiply(1)'s caller method "main()" 
 2. multiply(1)'s caller class where main() resides
 3. multiply function name

I don't want to add more parameters into multiply(1) such as

```
multiply(callerClassName, callerMethodName, calleeName, 1)
```

Is there a way to pass these manifest info to MyInvocationHandler.invoke while keeping original interface multiply(Int):Int?

Appreciate any clue!

Answer (score 1):

You can use stack trace to find out the caller characteristics. However you have to be careful if multiply is invoked from different threads.

You can access to stack trace as follows:

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```